# Mark task as successful in Locust (no HttpLocust)

Tags: locust

I am using Locust for load testing, my task is basically reading and publishing from/to PubSub. I noticed I don't get any statistics in the Locust UI, seems that it does it automatically if you use HttpLocust or can be forced using response.success() or response.failure(). Since I am not using HTTP calls in my task, is there a way I can signal the task as "successful" without the response object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to fire the success and failure events. The locust package provides an event that can be used to fire success or failure:
start_time = time.time()

```
try:
    # Do something
     total_time = int((time.time() - start_time) * 1000)
     events.request_success.fire(request_type="pubsub", name="publish", response_time=total_time, response_length=0)
except Exception as e:
     total_time = int((time.time() - start_time) * 1000)
     events.request_failure.fire(request_type="pubsub", name="publish", response_time=total_time, response_length=0, exception=e)
```